# boto3: Cannot update the event source mapping because it is in use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

basically im updating the event source mapping for a lambda trigger on an SQS to enable/disable it programmatically.

```
       #list all event sources for this new_name queue
       response = lada.list_event_source_mappings(
                EventSourceArn='arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:234234:' + newname,
                FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:234234:function:execute'
       )
       event_mappings = response["EventSourceMappings"]
       print str(event_mappings)
       for event_map in event_mappings:
           print "remove lambda trigger"
           #update them all with Disabled
           response = lada.update_event_source_mapping(
                UUID=event_map["UUID"],
                FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:234234:function:execute',
                Enabled=False
           )
```

I get this, I googled this error but nothing comes up.

```
An error occurred (ResourceInUseException) when calling the 
UpdateEventSourceMapping operation: 
Cannot update the event source mapping because it is in use.
```

why is this happening and how can I resolve this? I just want to programmatically enable/disable a given lambda trigger for a specific SQS.

Comment: What is the value of `event_map['State']` when this error occurs?

Comment: updating....i seee, how long is the wait usually?

Comment: Unsure.  Honestly, I was only speculating that this might be the issue, based on reading about the `ResourceInUseException` in the underlying [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html).  It sounds like you are trying to change something that you recently changed already.  Is that what's happening?  You may need to poll it in a loop (with a reasonable period of sleep) to wait for an appropriate state.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is a command that sent an async request, in order to wait for the result from the request you will need to create a loop to return the expected value as the following example:

```html
def loop_event_state(r_state, region, account_id, function, sqs):
    state = ''
    while state != r_state:
        event = get_event_mapping(region, account_id, function, sqs)
        state = str(event["EventSourceMappings"][0]["State"])
        print(f'Current state is {state}, required state is {r_state}')
        time.sleep(2)

        if state is r_state:
            break

    return state

def update_event_mapping(uuid, function, boolean, region, account_id, sqs):
    lambda_f.update_event_source_mapping(
        UUID=uuid,
        FunctionName=function,
        Enabled=boolean,
        BatchSize=10
    )

    if boolean is True:
        state = loop_event_state('Enabled', region, account_id, function, sqs)
    else:
        state = loop_event_state('Disabled', region, account_id, function, sqs)
    return state
```